# PHP array delete one item

Tags: php, arrays

Just a simple question - have this array:

```
 Array
(
    [year] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019
 [1] => 2020
        )

    [user] => usermail@gmail.com
)
```

I just want to completely remove `[user] => usermail@gmail.com` from this Array.

The user will have always only one ocurrence.

I tried `unset($filter['user'][0]);` also `unset($filter['user']);` but nothing works.

Comment: `unset` should do it. Can you please post code example so we can search the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [unset](https://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

```
<?php


 $array = Array
(
    "year" => Array
        (
            0 => 2019,
 1 => 2020
        ),

    "user"=> "usermail@gmail.com"
);


unset($array['user']);

print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: I think that what the OP does where he said in the question `unset($filter['user']);` - but it still doesn't work

Comment: @ dWinder,  yes, I tried the same it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually "[user] => usermail@gmail.com" is an array index not array.
You need to use this syntax

```
unset($array['user']);
```

here $array is the name of array.

Comment: I think that what the OP does where he said in the question `unset($filter['user']);` - but it still doesn't work